Is it possible to modify the font of NSIS Setup (without installing the font)?
I tried using the font from NSIS as shown below.
CreateFont $0 "Fonts installed on the system" 9 "500"
What I want to do is as follows:

Font files(.ttf) are included in the setup.
However, I would like to change the fonts on the Setup page without installing them in the user's System (Windows Fonts.)

The reason is that there is a separate deletion program,
I only want to delete the font directory installed in the previous setup, and I do not want to delete the fonts on the user's system.

(2024-07-08)
i was found font-info plugin
However, the API users and examples do not explain in detail how they are using it.

What is the minimum Windows version you need to support?

more than windows 7 :)

RequestExecutionLevel User
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
#!define EXAMPLE_SETALL ; Uncomment to set the font for all controls


!define /IfNDef FR_PRIVATE  0x10
!define /IfNDef FR_NOT_ENUM 0x20
!macro LoadCustomFont path
System::Call 'GDI32::AddFontResourceEx(t "${path}", i ${FR_PRIVATE}|${FR_NOT_ENUM}, p0)i'
!macroend
!macro FreeCustomFont path
System::Call 'GDI32::RemoveFontResourceEx(t "${path}", i ${FR_PRIVATE}|${FR_NOT_ENUM}, p0)i'
!macroend

var FontPath

!ifdef EXAMPLE_SETALL
SetFont "Cascadia Code PL" 8
!else
var CustomFontHandle
Page InstFiles "" OnInstFilesShow
Function OnInstFilesShow
    System::Call GDI32::DeleteObject(p$CustomFontHandle)
    !insertmacro FreeCustomFont $FontPath
    !insertmacro LoadCustomFont $FontPath
    GetDlgItem $0 $hWndParent 1 ; The Next/Close button
    CreateFont $CustomFontHandle "Cascadia Code PL" 8 400 /UNDERLINE
    SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETFONT} $CustomFontHandle 1
FunctionEnd
!endif

Function .onInit
${IfNot} ${Silent}
    InitPluginsDir
    StrCpy $FontPath "$PluginsDir\CascadiaCodePL.ttf"
    File "/oname=$FontPath" "CascadiaCodePL.ttf" #github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases
    !ifdef EXAMPLE_SETALL
        !insertmacro LoadCustomFont $FontPath
    !endif
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function .onGUIEnd
!ifndef EXAMPLE_SETALL
    System::Call GDI32::DeleteObject(p$CustomFontHandle)
!endif
!insertmacro FreeCustomFont $FontPath
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd


Thank you. Thanks to your answer, I did exactly what I wanted. @Anders

Unfortunately, my minimum reputation is 11,
so I couldn't make a 'useful vote' recommendation (more than 15) in this answer.

@tuxNeoh You can accept the answer...

@tuxNeoh see What should I do when someone answers my question?
